# Print just the value of Views field inside of views-view-fields template

Tags: views, theming, entities

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to print the value of a field in the 'fields' template.  Currently, I'm doing this to strip the unnecessary html (don't laugh):

```
<?php $shortContent = $fields['field_short_name']->content; ?>
<?php $shortText = strip_tags($shortContent); ?>
<?php $strategy = $fields['title']->content; ?>
<?php $cleanStrategy = strip_tags($strategy); ?>
<?php $company = $fields['field_money_manager_company']->content; ?>
<?php $cleanCompany = strip_tags($company); ?>


<?php echo '<img class="logo" src="/sites/all/themes/trust/img/mmx-logos/' . $shortText . '-logo.png" />'; ?>


<div class="row-heading">
    <?php echo '<h2>' . $cleanCompany. '</h2>'; ?>
    <?php echo '<h3>' . $cleanStrategy . '</h3>'; ?>
</div><!--end row-heading-->
```

How can I just get the value of the fields without having to print the entire 'content' and then strip the unnecessary elements?

Comment: The views UI provides configuration to strip out all the extra structural markup (see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/156358/print-just-field-data-from-a-view-into-a-block). You might be able to do that and forgo the templating altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to create a row header which contains some value from other fields. If it is your case, I will suggest you this solution.

---

Use **fields** in **format**

[image: Format of views]

Add field **Global: custom text**

[image: Global: custom text]

Then you can use the token, which is the value of field, with your custom HTML structure.

[image: Settings of custom text]

Please note that **custom text** field must be placed after the field you want to use. In my case, it is title. You need to exclude it from display, otherwise, there will be 2 titles.

[image]

Comment: He wants to strip/remove tags, not add more...

Comment: @NoSssweat He asked ** how to print the value of a field in the 'fields' template**. I just guess what he want is to customize the HTML structure of some of the field value.

Comment: Title says: "Print **just the value** of Views field inside of views-view-fields template" by "just the value" he means he doesn't want `<div>value</div>` he just wants `value`. Hence he is using the `strip_tags()` function, but he wants to know if there is a better/alternative way to achieve this.

Comment: @NoSssweat `<div class="row-heading">` make me think that he want a header for each row. So it makes sense to create a field to group some other field values. By using the token in **custom text**, it won't have <div> wrapper.

Comment: He also says `How can I just get the value of the fields without having to print the entire 'content' and then strip the unnecessary elements?` so idk how you concluded that, but if you want to leave the answer just in case, that's fine.

Comment: @NoSssweat No worry, I just try to give another way to solve the author's problem. If he think my approach does not fit his question, I will update or delete it.

Comment: I get it now, all along he just wanted to add fields to the header section.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I just get the value of the fields without having to print the
>   entire 'content' and then strip the unnecessary elements?

You can by using `raw` instead of `content`

```
<?php $fields['field_name']->raw; ?>
```

---

Alternatively, you could keep using `content`, but strip all the unecessary markup that views provides. My answer [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207740/is-there-a-more-performant-alternative-than-overriding-template-files/207741#207741) shows you how to.